# Which settings can I set to Codeanywhere project config for C++?

Tags: c++, project, codeanywhere

Hi there I am currently using Codeanywhere as an on-the-fly IDE for C++, to be able to easily code between different devices.
While setting the Codeanywhere environment, I ran into the "Project Config" file (that gear icon beside "Run Project" button), and I havent found nothing on this file's parameters.

I'm wondering if using this I could set compile and run settings (something like Visual Studio Code).

Am I missing an obscure documentation page?

Also could anyone explain those default settings?

```
Project Config C++ file

    {
      "run": [{
        "default": true,
        "devbox": "cpp_test"
      }]
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is [this](http://docs.codeanywhere.com/connections/containerconfig.html), but it doesn't seem to have much.

Comment: Yeah... (sigh) I was hoping that it would be more parameters that could improve build and run button using another languages. But thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 1):

This is most useful when *combined with the `undef` option in order to suppress warnings for* project-specific global variables. **Setting an entry to `true` enables reading and writing to that variable. Setting it to `false` will trigger JSHint to consider that variable** read-only.

Comment: You mean that I could enable applications to send errors in a container scope and gather those messages across different enviroments without installing something on each one?